# Реализация бэкапа на FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, резервное-копирование

Tсть сервер на FreeBSD? на нем висит куча сервисов - squid, openvpn, apache, mysql, на сервере настроена маршрутизация. Вопрос - если использовать только команды `cp` и `tar`, то какие директории и файлы вы бы копировали?

Answer (score 3):

По поводу утилит резервирования обязательно загляните [в руководство](http://www.freebsd.org.ru/handbook/backup-basics.html). Утилита `dump` - хороший вариант, чтобы сграбить целый раздел. Для отдельных каталогов я бы использовал `rsync`.

По поводу каталогов.

- Абсолютный минимум, который позволит накрыть все настройки:
  `/etc`, `/root`,
  `/usr/local/etc`, `/var/db/ports`,
  `/var/db/pkg`.
- Если крутится много сервисов, забирайте весь `/var` - там и базы данных, и почта.
- Для некоторых сервисов данные размещаются в `/usr/local`, например, корень данных веб-сервера Apache в FreeBSD обычно находится ниже `/usr/local/www`, надо проверять!
- Если есть пользователи, резервируйте `/usr/home`.

Рекомендую посмотреть [иерархию каталогов FreeBSD](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=hier&sektion=7), чтобы понять, нужно ли что-то еще. Тем более, если сервер достался "в наследство", кто его знает, какие тараканы были у предыдущего администратора.

Если сомневаетесь - проще сдампить весь раздел. И поспрашивать других практикующих администраторов на [форуме РутКод](http://admin.hashcode.ru).

Answer (score 0):

Для FreeBSD доступна ZFS с большим кол-вом "плюшек" полезных.
Для резервного копирования удобны "снапшоты".

mysql желательно копировать "родной" утилитой mysqldump иначе, есть риск потери некоторой части данных.

Для squid, openvpn из указанных обычно достаточно делать копию конфиг-файлов. Да учетных данных (логины-пароли). Для apache еще желательно содержимое самих сайтов.